# How can i get inverted coma instead of apostrophe in wordpress content frontend

Tags: wordpress

I write inverted comma on admin tinymce editor but on frontend it displays an apostrophe when I use:

```
the_content();
```

But when I use

```
echo get_the_content();
```

it will display inverted comma.

And when I use

```
$content=get_the_content();
$content=apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
echo $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
```

it again display apostrophe instead of inverted comma.

I try to replace apostrophe by comma using

```
str_replace("’", "'", $content);
```

It doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Look at the actual html output to your webpage. The character you're interested in is likely an html entity, like `&rsquo;`. Can you tell us what it  is?

Comment: when i insert   k'g then i get output as k’g  &rsquo; will give us apostrophe but we need comma

Comment: And is that what the source displays? For example, your comment here on SO has the html: ```when i insert k&#39;g then i get output as k’g```

Comment: im working on Nepali language integration on admin content editor, when i inserted content like  k'g{  this then it will give me  k’g{  but on admin editor display ' this symbol. similarly on database posts table it is ok but while i use the_content the it replace commas by apostrophe

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this one

```
<?php $content = get_the_content();
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );
    $content = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $content);
    $content = html_entity_decode($content);//added extra code
    echo $content = str_replace("’", "'", $content);
?>
```

> adding

```
$content = html_entity_decode($content);
```

> this code then it works for me.
>   But still didn't know why WordPress convert.